# php : POST & INSERT to SQL database, the 'id' from URL

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a URL : `http://webaddress.php?id=100`

I am trying to insert the 'id' value of 100 into a column in my SQL table.

I have tried the following:

```
$productid = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['id']); 

$insertsql = "INSERT INTO TableName(table column)
        VALUES('$productid')";
```

can anyone advise on the correct approach? thanks

Comment: Its not a POST, its a GET

Comment: This is `$_GET` argument so read is as `$_GET['id']` or change your form to send `$_POST` data

Comment: Use PDO or prepared statements to [prevent sql injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). I think you need to show us more code where do you declare your varible `$rating`?

Comment: **Warning!!!** Your code is open for [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), please use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) preferably with [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My comment was getting a bit long so I post it as an answer.

Like others said. If you send a value with the url to your script so you need to get it with `$_GET` instead of `$_POST` To make sure the id is really a number you could use `(int)` like `$productid = (int)$_GET['id'];` . The `(int)` will turn your variable into a number, if its not a number it will return `0`
So you could also make a checj before your query if the $productID is larger then 0 to prevent allot og zero's in your database

Also use the isset function like `$productID = isset($_GET['id']) ? (int)$_GET['id'] : 0` so if some one visit your url without the parameter id he wont get an undefined error.

For your queries please use prepared statements or PDO to [prevent sql injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

EDIT:
On w3schools I found some nice explaination and examples about [prepared statements and PDO](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) try to implement those examples into your own project

Second EDIT:
I was reading the example of prepared statements of the link I posted, and they make 1 small mistake in my opinion.
After the `$stmt->execute()` they asume the data is inserted correcly. But to make sure the data is really inserted you schould change that part into:

```
// Check if there is really inserted some rows into the database or not
if ($stmt->affected_rows > 0) {
  echo "New records created successfully";
}
```

Comment: I would say *need to get it with $_GET OR $_POST*. In general acording to many CRUD rules sending forms should be used with `method="post"` for security reasons (especially when working with sensitive data and/or want to *minimalize* risk of data manipulation by curious users. Let's say that's rating system it's easy to run a call i.e. `domain.tld/rate.php?points=10000000` insted of just `100`.

Comment: @biesior I agree with you. Form data almost always needs to be posted also te prevent the data to get logged into server log files

Comment: "*prevent the data to get logged into server log files*" that what I meant writing about sensitive data.